# How to export mysql data only if "rare" column value = 1

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got an id grabbing script for a website and the dump.php selects all of the id's from the DB and dumps the id's cleanly into a .txt file. I was wondering how to modify it so it only dumps the id's  deemed as "rare"; that is, the id grabber marks id's with patters as "rare" and assigns the "rare" column in the database to 1 while keeping "normal" id's as 0

```
$ids = $sql->select('*', '`ids` ORDER BY `UserId` ASC', NULL, NULL, NULL, true, true);
```

Is the current script, how do i get it to select the column "rare" where value = 1

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ids WHERE rare = 1`? Just out of interest what are the nulls and booleans in the function call? Also, I don't really see the point in that function at all, all it does is add in the words `SELECT` and `FROM`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the current script, how do i get it to select the column "rare" where value = 1

Exactly like you wrote:

> select <strike>the column</strike> rare from ids where <strike>value</strike> rare = 1